# Babel with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Why isn't this working in IE11 ?

I was under the impression that Babel will automatically convert new-style code to old-style. Is there some configuration setup to be done ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Babel Test</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
{
    (async () =>
    {
        const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
        const content = await response.json();
        alert(content.title);
    })();    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are making a GET request. You aren't POSTing JSON. You aren't PUTting JSON. It doesn't make sense to put `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in your headers (nor does it make sense to include `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` which does the same thing but for jQuery which you aren't using).

Comment: Sorry about that - I have edited my code - I was initially trying a POST but for the sake of this question, I switched to GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Babel can transform language features from newer versions of JavaScript into equivalents in older versions.

It can't polyfill APIs which aren't supported (like `fetch`). You would need to find an explicit `fetch` polyfill for that.

---

Additionally, the browser-side version of Babel will only transform scripts marked as `type="text/babel"` and (before you edited the question) you didn't have any of those so your arrow functions, `async` and `await` keywords wouldn't have be transformed.

Comment: So what is my best bet to write code to support IE11 which is not a React / Angular / Vue setup ?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. I'd use Babel, but I'd do it at build time not run time, and I'd use libraries with IE support instead of raw fetch … but first I'd argue strongly against support IE in the first place.

Comment: "but first I'd argue strongly against support IE in the first place" - there are IE users for this particular B2C product. I can't suggest not to support IE at all. I was thinking of not using jQuery but now I realise that's the only option.

Comment: "there are IE users for this particular B2C product" — Consider those users, if you subtract the ones who will migrate to a browser that has had more than a security update in the last 8 years, will they generate enough profit to make it worth the extra development (including testing) costs of support IE11?

Comment: "I was thinking of not using jQuery but now I realise that's the only option." — XMLHttpRequest. Axios. Plenty of options.

Comment: 1. I'm not management. 2. jQuery is faster / easier to develop for IE.